# Does the eq() matcher can be applied to double?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

There is a rule about matchers for parameters of stubbed method: all parameters are all matchers. An InvalidUseOfMatchersException will be thrown if matchers are combined with raw values. In this situation, the eq() matcher will help. For example, I want to verify any integer divided by 0 will throw MyException. The stubbed div() has two parameters. The first is given by anyInt(), the second is given by eq(0) rather than raw 0.

```
public interface MatcherDemo {
     double div(int x, int y) throws Exception;
}

@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    when(demo.div(anyInt(), eq(0))).thenThrow(new MyException());
    demo.div(5, 0);
}
```

But, I found that the eq() matcher can not be applied to double. If the div()'s signature is modified such as:

```
double div(double x, double y) throws Exception;
```

then the Mockito will throw an InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

I wonder if this is because the comparison of double can not be done precisely, and how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you tried, but using

```
when(demo.div(anyDouble(), eq(0d))).thenThrow(new MyException());
```

doesn`t seem to have any problems.

Maybe you forgot to change the eq(0) expression to a double as well?
But I get a UnnecessarStubbing Exception in that case, because it doesn`t map to the correct method.

(Tested with JUnit 5 & Mockito 2.27.0)